# What is the interchange of nutrients between plants called?

Tags: botany, mycology

I've heard about how fungi is the nutrient super highway of the plant web. What is this interchange between plants and the fungi called?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mycorrhizal_network

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all the exchange takes place at a molecular level, it can be called  **Bidirectional transportation/ Bidirectional transfer** of minerals, carbon, and other nutrients.

During the symbiotic association, the fungus grows either inter- or intra-cellularly in the host plant's root system to create certain interfaces between both symbionts. These interfaces are often termed as **symbiotic interfaces**, which are simply membranes of both the symbionts' cells separated by an interface space.

Like a normal bio-membrane, these membranes/symbiotic interfaces also have different types of transporter proteins, channels, ion-gates which have their regular role in the transportation of molecules across the membrane. The compositions of these symbiotic interfaces differ from species to species.

[image: Different transported can be seen located on the membrane of both symbiotic cells.]

The process of interchange of nutrients is similar to what takes place between two cells. It depends on the concentration of molecules, charge, size etc.

For more info- ***http://www.davidmoore.org.uk/21st_Century_Guidebook_to_Fungi_PLATINUM/REPRINT_collection/Ferrol_etal_nutrient_transport.pdf***

Answer (score 0):

Mycorrhizal associations. These are mutualistic associations between the roots of plants and the mycelium of fungi. The plants and fungi both benefit. The plants gets improved access to nutrients deep in the soil and the fungi get access to the photosynthetic carbohydrates made by the plants.

Here is a good source: https://www.pnas.org/content/116/46/23163

Comment: what 1 or two words is the specific interchange between 2 plants, or fungi and plant called, since the whole system is the mycorrhizal network?